# Tapping on indexes doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I use segues for both push on cell and detail disclosure button.
I can't tap on indices, because detail disclosure button "intercepts" touch instead.

[image]

Code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
                 sender:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Dossier Segue"]) {
        Person *person = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        DSRevealViewController *vc = (DSRevealViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.person = person;
        vc.transitioningDelegate = self;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Info"]) {
        Person *person = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSAssert(person, @"Person is nil");
        PersonInfoViewController *vc = (PersonInfoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.person = person;
    }
}
```

P.S. I checked my other app where I use table view delegate methods instead of segues, and it works well.